# Why is error message not showing when applied on RadioButtons or Checkboxes

Tags: java, android, validation

So I have this form. I am applying errors on the widgets with the following method

```
editText.setError("Please write at least 5 characters");
checkBox.setError("Please, choose");
radioButton.setError("Please, choose");
```

But the text for the **RadioButtons** and for the **Checkboxes** does not seem to show. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Share more code of yours ts and html.

Comment: I have put the wrong tag sorry. It is an android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is showing red mark your code is working perfectly fine because setError() method is only available for widgets that extend TextView. But gladly all relevant Widgets for error messages do inherit from TextView: EditText, AutoCompleteTextView, CheckBox and RadioButton (well, the hierarchy is weird, but never mind).But there is one problem with using this approach. The message text is only visible when the view has the focus. Otherwise Android only displays the red marker. Try setting the focus on a touch screen with a radio button or a check box